# How to access a key vault in console application running on local machine?

Tags: c#, azure-keyvault

**Descriprion:**

I have one console application which sync the data from 1 azure db to another azure db. Now for security, I want store those azure db connection strings in key vault and access it in my console app. As I said in title I am running this console application on my local machine, it is not hosted on azure and also it is not using any authentication like azure AD, so I can't use client Id , client secret to access key vault.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this wheel wasn't invented already? Did you do some research if Azure provides you with such a service, maybe some service that keeps database continuously in sync automatically? If that's not available, I'd look into potential open source tooling for database synchronization, e.g. https://www.symmetricds.org/ (disclaimer: I have no stakes there), or maybe some database systeem built-in feature (MS SQL Server, PostGreSQL, etc.)

I know, my answer is not really a solution, but maybe it helps anyway.